# Gradle Artifactory Chain of Libraries

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I have my Android Studio project (A) with dependencies linked to a private Maven (Artifactory). Gradle is resolving the libraries published and everything goes well.

My problem is: I have an library on artifactory (B) that has his own dependencies of another libraries in gradle (such as AWS, picaso, and other external libs). My main project (A) resolves the dependency of my library, but fails to compile because he cant locate these sub-dependencies of library B. Works only if, in my project A, I put these compiles again (AWS, picaso), but I think this is wron because breaks the "chain of dependencies" and is resulting in redundant code.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: How do you add the dependency of B in the main project? As gradle dependency or as an aar?

Comment: Hi gabriele... as gradle dependency (compile 'com.mybusiness.mylibrarie:1.0.0')

Comment: Can you check the pom file in the maven server? In this file you should find if the dependencies are reported in the right way.